# Mongoose: $push wrong value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm push EventId like this

```
CreateEvent.save(function(err){
       User.findByIdAndUpdate(currentUser._id,{$push :{EventIds:CreateEvent._id}},function(ex){
          if (ex)
          {
            console.log("Exception : " + ex);
          }
        });
    });
```

_id pushed wrong in User document. Correct _id :

ObjectId("53139448d4509d391c000006")

But it pushed like this:

ObjectId("53139448d4509d391c000011")

While last two character wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing more code, but my hunch is that you're doing this in a loop and `CreateEvent` is no longer the object you think it is.  The second parameter to the `save` callback is a better choice for use as the saved event when getting its `_id`:

```
CreateEvent.save(function(err, event) {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(currentUser._id, {$push: {EventIds: event._id}}, 
        function(ex) {
            if (ex)
            {
                console.log("Exception : " + ex);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In that particular case, @JohnnyHK is probably right, but I can confirm this can happen in at least one other situation as well.

Let's define a schema:

```
var Event = new mongoose.Schema({
  logo: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Media' },
  name: { type: String },
  logo: { type: String }
};
```

Obviously, `logo` is defined twice, but the behavior is rather surprising. Now, say we have this `Media` document:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("546310bbe837bf000011ac71")
  "name": "xyz.jpg"
}
```

Now, let's attach that media to an event:

```
event.logo = media;
```

I'm not exactly sure why, but `event.logo`'s value instead became:

```
ObjectId("546310bbe837bf000011ac72")
```

The same id, offset by 1.